# How to make this 3D star with folded edges?

Tags: origami

I have found this beautiful star, but nowhere a guide how to fold it.

I don’t want to disassemble it as it is a decoration at a local café.

Would someone help me to identify how is it called and more importantly, how to fold it? I guess we need 3-4 pieces of rectangular paper and the star completes once the parts are put together, but it’s my wild guess.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shape is called the "origami omega star". It is folded from 6 equal pieces of paper. The folding itself is not too complicated, but the assembly is quite hard to understand.

Here's [just one video manual](https://youtu.be/xKmgqv8N3-4), you can find many more when searching for the correct name.

Comment: Excellent! That’s exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :))